# How to apply Multithreading in "for-loop" in python efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am calculating cosine value between two values in a for loop,I want to know can how to apply multi threading and increase efficiency in my program.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import time

questionset=[]
for i in range(0,8000):
    questionset.append(i)


cos_sims=[]



start_time = time.time()
for question in questionset:
   sims = cosine_similarity(question, 0.5)
   cos_sims.append(sims)
print("--- %s seconds in question filter---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Time to complete the loop for cos value calculation is around 1 second , i want it to reduce it in ms

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the list cos_sims matter?

Comment: Also the code you have so far cannot be run.

Comment: For pure computation on a single processor system, multithreading will likely increase processing time. This is more likely to be optimized through changes in algorithm.  cosine calculation could be an expensive operation, so caching cosine values in a lookup table could help.

Comment: @Gledi the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

With the multiprocessing library you can use a Pool map like this example from the docs

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

just use cosine_simularity as f and rather than printing it assign it to your output list (cos_sims)

Comment: Although as mentioned by @RufusVS this may not be the quickest solution